# Excel - "referencing"

Tags: excel, reference

I have two columns, B and F. In F, I have a formula and then I apply it through entire column F, but this formula should have the same 'cell number' as it is in **B**, e.g. cell B5 has formula =Sheet2!$C$**9** and then:

F5 should have =Sheet2!$D**9**   --- I will write the first 'cell letter' (D)

F6 should have =Sheet2!$D**4**   --- B6 =Sheet2!$C$**4**

F7 should have =Sheet2!$D**11**   --- B7  =Sheet2!$C$**11**
...

Comment: What is the logic in the jumps from row 9, down to 4 and back up to 11?

Comment: Looks like you are referencing located single values for any reason. To be honest, best way for that is just doing it manually, unless you make some kind of relation between rows (your example does not have it because you jump from row 9 to 4 and back to 11)

Comment: If you really must, and the formulas in B are all consistent other than the row numbers, you could do something weird like: `=INDEX(Sheet2!D:D,SUBSTITUTE(UPPER(FORMULATEXT(B2)),"=SHEET2!$C$",""))`

Answer (score 0):

I would add a helper column (Column C in my example) for the row that should be referenced - then you can use INDEX to get the values:

[image]